# How to properly use Laravel localization language-string as vue.js script data property

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, this, laravel-localization

I have a sweetalert inside a vue.js script (vue.js component script 2 snippet) which is working properly with two Laravel localization language-strings. Now I'm trying to use the same language strings as data properties inside another vue.js component script.

Problem: It don´t accept the following sides.name properties.

**vue.js component script 1 snippet**

```
<script>
  data: () => ({ 
            sides: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: this.__('offers.front'),
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: this.__('offers.back'),
                }
            ],
    }),
</script>
```

The console displays the following error message:

> app.js:247950 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__')"

Here is the snippet of the sweetalert2 Swal which is working properly:

**vue.js component script 2 snippet**

```
<script>
                Swal.fire(
                    this.__('offers.front'),
                    this.__('offers.back'),
                    'success'
                )
</script>
```

I tried it with without "this" but then the output in the template obviously becomes "offers.front".

Comment: based on the console error it looks like you don't get anything back from the lodash, can you provide some code on how you registered the translation files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>
  data: () => ({ // WITHOUT CONTEXT
            sides: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: this.__('offers.front'), // THIS ERROR
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: this.__('offers.back'),
                }
            ],
    }),
</script>
```

Please update for

```
<script>
  data() {
    return { 
            sides: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: this.__('offers.front'),
                }
            ]
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I have now dealt more intensively with the "this" context and understand that the problem was due to the wrong "data" writing in this case

Comment: I thought you'd like it.